# Remapping a face in font lock mode

Tags: faces, font-lock

Given this headline:

```
** Title
Title Title Title
```

The headline has the face "org-level-2" applied. This face has been applied by means of a regexp, using font-lock.

Let's assume that "org-level-2" is set as follows:

```
((t
 (:height 1.5
  :weight bold 
  :extend nil 
  :foreground "black")))
```

Now, I'd like to apply a custom face for all occurrence of "Title":

```
(defface my-face
  '((t :foreground "red"))
  "test")

(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  `(("Title" . 'my-face)))
```

The word "Title" in the headline should  have a relative height of 1.5, a bold weight and a red foreground. However, it is just red, with normal size and normal weight.

I'd like both faces to "mix" together. How can I achieve this?

Is font-lock the way to go if i want to remap faces based on regexp?

Comment: I think your question isn't really Org-mode specific. Consider removing that part, or at least tag `org-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `my-face` inherit from `org-level-2`, you can add `:inherit 'org-level-2` to the definition of `my-face`. This way `my-face` will have the right size and weight.

Comment: Thank you for replying! However, I'd like "my-face" to mix with whatever face is already applied, not just org-level-2. Sort of like applying multiple faces to the same text.

Comment: Then I think you have to deal with the [text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html) of the occurrences of `Title`.